# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can anyone tell me why I get the following error when I use the code below..
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

```
    Dim newOrderID As Guid = Guid.Parse(orderID)
    Dim DBConnect2 As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect2.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect2.Command(db, "SelectWebLinkVisible")

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("orderID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = newOrderID

        db.Open()
        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Dim webLinkVisible As Boolean

        While DR.Read
            webLinkVisible = DR("webLinkVisible")
        End While

        DR.Close()
        DR = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
```

I've even tried replacing the WHILE bit with the following and thought the page would redirect as the data it's trying to read is surely NULL but it doesn't do anything..

```
        While DR.Read
            If DR("webLinkVisible") is nothing Then
                Response.Redirect("www.bbc.co.uk")
            End If
        End While
```

Comment: Side notes: you don't need to call `Close` or `Dispose` on `db`, that's what the end of the `using` block does for you implicitly. If you're gonna keep them, you should reverse the calls (don't call `Close` after you've `Dispose`d). Your reader and command should also be wrapped in `using`s as well. There's also no need to assign `Nothing` to those values as they go out of scope anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a field contains a NULL value the OleDbDataReader return the value DBNull.Value. This is not the same thing as Nothing.
To handle this scenario you could use the [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
While DR.Read
    If Not DR.IsDBNull(DR.GetOrdinal("webLinkVisible")) Then
        webLinkVisible = DR("webLinkVisible")
    End If
End While
```

The extra call to DR.GetOrdinal is required because IsDBNull cannot work with the field name but it requires the ordinal position of the field as returned by your query.

Comment: Just tried this. Many thanks for the reply. Still getting same error :-( Any other suggestions appreciated.@Steve

Comment: My fault. Forgot to add a Not before the check for DBNull